# Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql::addColumn()

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

When i try to run my upgrade script it gives `Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql::addColumn()` error on second addcolumn but when i remove all other column and keep only one `addColumn` it work fine.My upgrade script is as below

```
    $installer->startSetup();

/**
 * alter table 'savecart/savecart'
 */

 $installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('savecart/savecart'),'savecart_name', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'Savecart Name'
        ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('savecart/savecart'),'savecart_comment', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'comment'   => 'Savecart Comment'
        ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('savecart/savecart'),'savecart_bill_id', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length'    => 10,
        'comment'   => 'Billing Id'
        ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('savecart/savecart'),'savecart_valid_till', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'comment'   => 'Valid Till Date'
        ));


$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

**CHAINING CORRECTLY**

I was looking into this and found several sites that use a different writing method:

http://magedevguide.com/challenge/chapter4/1

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-setup-magento-scripts

Please try these methods with your values..
You can try copy pasting following code, but please review it for your values..

```
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * alter table 'savecart/savecart'
 */

$installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('savecart/savecart'))
    ->addColumn('savecart_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array('nullable' => true), 'Savecart Name')
    ->addColumn('savecart_comment', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array('nullable' => true), 'Savecart Comment')
    ->addColumn('savecart_bill_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, array('nullable' => true), 'Billing Id')
    ->addColumn('savecart_valid_till', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array('nullable'  => true), 'Valid Till Date');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Please let me know if one of the solutions is working so I can update my answer.

Comment: i have updated question and removed semi column but not working i have already tried with second answer that i know but i want to know why chaining not working in this script.it should work as magento support this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following upgrade script add multiple columns to the existing magento table.for detailed explanation.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/upgrade-script-multiple-columns-magento/

```
$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('imagedetail'),'filters_workshop_colour', 
    array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable' => true,
    'comment' => 'Filters Workshop Colour'
));
$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('imagedetail'),'splashbackcolor', 
    array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable' => true,
    'comment' => 'Splash Back Color'
    ));
$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('imagedetail'),'cabinetcolor', 
    array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable' => true,
    'comment' => 'Cabinet Color'
    ));
```